# Simple interface for reinforcement learning

Tags: python, interface, reinforcement-learning

I have a reinforcement learning algorithm written in Python and I would like to build a very simple interface for it (Input and output form). As I am a dummy beginner in programming I would like to know the simplest way to do it (I have some html knowledge). Can you give me some practical direction?

p.s.I am working on Cloud9, if it matters.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use some GUI frameworks and there are many available out there (most of them are free):

Have a look in [Python GUI Programming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) or [Kivy website](https://kivy.org/#home).

But I don't think Cloud9 have any of them installed or maybe I'm wrong (test and let me know!)

Answer (score 0):

[tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/) is definitely the easiest way to get started. You will have trouble using any GUI framework with a cloud IDE however because they typically wrap system frameworks only available to native applications.